# 2d arrays specification in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to define a 2d array in verilog but I don't understand them very well in the way they are assigned. What I mean is if I define an array like

```
reg [6:0] array[7:0]
```

I hope I defined an array with 8 rows and 7 columns. If a number is assigned lets say:

```
array[0] = 7'b1100000; array[1] = 7'b0101000;
```

In what order are they placed? My intention is to read the first bit in every row.
So if I read like this do I get the result:

```
array[0][0]-->should give 1(the first bit of first row)
array[0][1]-->should give 0(the first bit of second row)
```

So is my assignment way correct? Or should I play with the order like:

```
reg array[0:6] array[0:7]
```

Comment: Which bit do you consider to be the "first", the MSB or the LSB of a word? You need to define your bit and word indices accordingly.

Comment: MostSignificantBit

Comment: What happens when you simulate your code? Did you get any errors when you tried to compile your proposed line of code at the bottom of your question?

Comment: NO I don't get any errors

Comment: Why don't you try loading array[0] with 7'h55 and array[1] with 7'h2A, then see what you get for array[0][0] and array[0][1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of the latest [SystemVerilog](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) (supperset of Verilog) LRM. Available for from [IEEE](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html).

Read section 7.4 "Packed and unpacked arrays". Pay special attention to section 7.4.4 and 7.4.5.

Below is example code:

```
parameter P = 6:0;
parameter U = 7:0;
// {[packed_range]} name {[unpacked_range]};
reg       [P]      array        [U]; // U unpacked of packed sized P
reg   [1:0] [P]   array2; // 1:0 packed of packed size P
reg   [0:1] [P]   array3; // 0:1 packed of packed size P
initial begin
array[0] = 7'b1100000; // assign the packed portion of unpacked
array[1] = 7'b0101000;
array2[0] = array[0]; array2[1] = array[1];
array3[0] = array[0]; array3[1] = array[1];
//                  U  P
$display("%b",array[0][0]); // prints 0 -- U's entry 0, P's entry 0
$display("%b",array[0][1]); // prints 0 -- U's entry 0, P's entry 1
$display("%b",array[0][3]); // prints 0 -- U's entry 0, P's entry 3
$display("%b",array[1][3]); // prints 1 -- U's entry 1, P's entry 3
$display("%d",array[0][6:4]); // prints 6 -- U's entry 0, P's range 6:4
$display("%d",array[1][6:4]); // prints 2 -- U's entry 1, P's range 6:4
$display("%d",array[1]); // prints 28 -- U's entry 1, P's range 6:0 (implied)
//$display("%d",array[1:0][0]); // ** ILLEGAL
//$display("%d",array); // ** ILLEGAL cannot print unpacked
$display("%b",array2[1][3]); // prints 1 -- [1:0]'s entry 1, P's entry 3
$display("%d",array3[1]); // prints 28 -- [0:1]'s entry 1, P's range 6:0 (implied)
$display("%b",array2); // prints 01010001100000 -- implies {array2[1],array2[0]}
$display("%b",array3); // prints 11000000101000 -- implies {array3[0],array3[1]}
end
```